# User specific settings, limited by role

Tags: options, settings-api

I generally know how create plugin settings, and limit a users access to these plugin's settings based on their [role or capability](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/how-can-i-allow-the-editor-role-to-change-theme-settings). However in this case, I want the user to be able to create settings that effect the plugin's behaviour for *only* their account, not the plugin's global behaviour.

For example, I want the user to be able to upload an image from the plugin's option screen, and have that image appear in the footer of only their own post content. This would not effect anyone else's settings.

Where I'm stuck, and having difficulty researching, is how to get these settings to apply to just one user.

Any resources, examples, articles or discussions welcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: Discussion of merits of user_option or user_metta http://diegolamonica.info/wordpress-differences-between-update_user_meta-and-update_user_option/

Comment: Finally found a similar question on wpse: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27690/save-user-specific-options-in-wordpress-admin

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_option

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

Comment: Looks like `update_user_option` is a poor choice if portability is a concern, as by default it appends the database prefix to the option name. `update_user_meta` however does not. So if you ever migrate sites, and the setting you are trying to manage are not site or install specific, then `update_user_meta` is the way to go.

Comment: It looks like the Settings API is fairly limited for this use case, as only those with `manage_options` capability and above would be able to access/submit the settings page. I want these options to be set-able by anyone who can submit a post. One option might be to add fields to the user's profile page....

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/